Vscode go combination cannot jump
Vscode go combination cannot jump. "Delete()" can junp, But "Create()" not.
Have you encountered any big shots? If you have any solutions, thank you very much.
demo:
import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := NewNomal()
    a.Create()
    a.Delete()

}

func Funnn(a map[int]bool) {
    a[2] = false
}

type Nomal interface {
    Delete()
    Create()
}

func NewNomal() Nomal {
    return &Person{}
}

type Person struct {
    *Per
}

type Per struct {
}

func (p *Person) Delete() {
    fmt.Println("delete person")

}

func (p *Per) Create() {
    fmt.Println("create per")
}

Create and Delete jump

What do you mean with “jump”?

"jump"  mean Command + Left arrow key

When I'm selecting Delete in the Nomal interface I can select “Go to Implementations” and jump to func (p *Person) Delete() because *Person implements the Nomal interface and therefore this function is an implementation of this method.
On the other Hand *Per does not implement the Nomal interface, so func (p *Per) Create() is not an implementation of the Create() method.
Method Create of the embedded field *Per in the struct Person is promoted to Person.Create, so Person implements Nomal without having a implementation for Create itself.
That is the reason you can't jump to the implementation: There is none, and VS Code has no “jump to promoted implementations” command that I know of.

Thank you very much for your answer. If not, that would be a pity. You can find it in Goland

You can go to the implementation in Golang, but not from the implementation to method specification for Create. So it's similar.
Please Mark the answer as the accepted answer or useful if it was useful. Thanks.
